# Linux can't apply "find" in a pipe

Tags: shell, command-line, find

I am searching for a file in the directory tree below me. When I try `find . -name xyz`, I get screenfuls of `find: '/home/fred' : Permission denied`

That makes sense as I don't have access rights to those directories. So I try

```
find . -name xyz | grep -v Permission
```

which should remove the lines I don't want. Well, I exactly the same screenfuls as before. The grep doesn't do anything

What's going on and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

"Permission denied" is a warning and not the kind data you'd expect from `find`. In order to keep error messages separate from the requested user data, `find` prints the filenames to its standard output channel 1 and the warning to the standard error channel 2. This behaviour is very common among many unix command-line tools. The shell typically displays both channels. You can avoid it by explicitly re-directing the error stream somewhere else, e.g. the void represented by `/dev/null`:

```
find . -name xyz 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: _The shell has the habit of displaying both channels._ This sounds a bit like a weakness. Actually one would even want channel "error" 2 in red i.e. "on top of" normal output. If the shell has a habit, it is letting you choose between default "split but displayed together", or suppress like you show, or merge like I show, or log with `2>errorfile`. (just a side note on that word -- good answer)

Comment: @rastafile Good point. I adjusted the wording.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that you're trying to filter out (remove) the error messages from the standard output of `find`.  Error messages (and general diagnostic messages, as well as interactive prompts) are displayed on the standard error stream, which can't be piped. You therefore can't get rid of the error messages using `grep` (without merging the standard error stream into the standard output stream).

Using GNU `find` (which implements the nonstandard `-readable` test):

```
find . -type d ! -readable -prune -o -name xyz -print
```

This would look for anything called `xyz` in or below the current directory and print out the found pathnames.  Whenever `find` encounters a directory that the current user does not have access to read, this directory is removed from the search tree (the search tree is *pruned* with `-prune`).

This gets rid of the "permission denied" errors originating from trying to access directories that you can't access.  It does this by simply not getting into situations where these errors would be generated.

By avoiding `grep`, this will also avoid accidentally filtering out files found in directories called, literally, `Permission`.  It also allows you to see any *other* errors that may be generated while searching for `xyz` (whatever these errors might be), or to write in-line scripts, executed through `find ... -exec ...` that may want to use the error stream, or to use `find ... -ok ...` for asking the user for confirmation before performing some action.